# Why does this return empty strings?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to access the values of an associative array in PHP. I populate the array using the following loop in PHP:

```
$db = array("a","b","c");
foreach ($db as $q) {
    $$q = 'value';
}
```

**This version prints the correct values**

```
foreach ($db as $q) {
    echo '<li>'; echo $$q; echo '</li>';
}
\\THIS GIVES ME THE CORRECT OUTPUT <li>value</li><li>value</li><li>value</li>
```

**But I want to access the values through their index**

```
$num = count($db);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    echo '<li>'; echo $$db[$i]; echo '</li>';
}
\\\\THIS GIVES ME THE WRONG OUTPUT (EMPTY STRINGS <li></li><li></li><li></li>
```

What is going wrong in the second version? How can I access the values in this associative array through an index correctly?

Comment: remove the extra `$` = `echo $db[$i];`

Comment: Doesnt that return the keys? How do I get the values?

Comment: no, did you bother to test it

Comment: yes. $db[$i] returns the keys, like "<li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li>".

Comment: they are the values, the keys are 0,1,2 `$db = array("a","b","c"); print_r($db);` = Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c )

Comment: yes I get that but shouldnt there be through the double dollar sign a new variable name that I should be able to access?

Comment: no, and i dont know why you think there should be.

Comment: i think i see the confusion, but don't know the actual user case, you want to parse by reference (http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). there is no way your 2nd block of code produces `<li>value</li><li>value</li><li>value</li>` to do that in the first block you need `foreach ($db as &$q) {` <<note the apesand

Comment: No, what he is trying is to get the value of a variable knowing its name. Which is achieved by using the double dollar notation, thus: `$a= 'hi'; $b='a'; echo $$b;` would print 'hi'. But he is facing an ambiguity problem. Look at my answer below.

Comment: look at the first 2 pieces of code he is turning a,b,c to value,value,value (or tying to)

Comment: Not really, look at the first foreach. In the first iteration $q is = 'a', so `$$q` is an alias for `$a`, thus, in this iteration he is defining `$a = 'value'`, in the second one `$b = 'value'`, and in the last one `$c = 'value'`. I don't know why he is using this awkward  method though, but that doesn't mean that it's not correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
    echo '<li>'; echo $$db[$i]; echo '</li>';
```

In this line is one `$` too much. Write:

```
    echo '<li>'; echo $db[$i]; echo '</li>';
```

This should do the trick.

**PS**: You don't have to write `echo` everytime. Use string concatenation:

```
    echo '<li>' . $db[$i] . '</li>';
```

Comment: Doesnt that return the keys? How do I get the values?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do something quite strange, anyway the solution to your problem are braces: `{ }`

```
$num = count($db);
for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
    echo '<li>'; echo ${$db[$i]}; echo '</li>';
}
```

Look how braces are resolving the ambiguity, since without them, php wouldn't know if you were referring to `${$db}[$i]` or `${$db[$i]}`